# how to add rvm to super user

Tags: ruby, rvm, sudo, init.d

hi i need to execute a ruby program from a init script i need to run the script as

```
sudo /etc/bin/differ.sh start
```

but the problem is rvm is not installed on root(super user) . so code in the differ script  *ruby "filename"* wont execute because the gems and rvm is not installed in root.

i need solve how to add rvm and its gems to root  (i have not installed by system wide installation).i have even tried the rvmsudo

```
rvmsudo ruby "filename"
```

but it's not working in script works good in terminal.
please free to ask any files or outputs i will  post along with this question.

Answer (score 1):

This page on integrating RVM with init.d may help: https://rvm.io/integration/init-d